# Excel Index Function Email Listing With Empty Columns

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, duplicates

I have a list of emails ranging from cells C2:L1000. Some of these cells are blank. Some cells contain the same email as other cells. I am trying to make a list of all the emails in a single column that filters out repeating values and empty cells. What function or VBA would help me achieve this goal?

Comment: Use Excel's basic function `Remove Duplicates`. If you google it or look it up on youTube, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't very effecient, but maybe it will give you some ideas of how too accomplish what you're looking for. Good luck

```
Sub RunThisCode()
Dim rcell As Range, Column2PlaceValues As Range, RangeOfEmailAddress As Range

Set Column2PlaceValues = Range("M:M").EntireColumn
Set RangeOfEmailAddress = Rangee("C2:L1000")


For Each rcell In RangeOfEmailAddress.Cells


    If IsEmpty(rcell) Then
        'do nothing

    ElseIf Not (Test4Match(rcell, Column2PlaceValues)) Then
        Cells(Rows.Count, Column2PlaceValues.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rcell.Value

    End If


Next rcell


End Sub


Private Function Test4Match(rcell As Range, Column2PlaceValues As Range) As Boolean

On Error GoTo NOPE
    Test4Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(rcell.Value, Column2PlaceValues, 0)
Exit Function

NOPE:

End Function
```

Comment: I updated this with a better answer. I'm pretty sure it will give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you, the first update did what I needed. I added it to my other macro which runs on opening the workbook. I ended with "Dim rcell As Range, ColumnToPlaceValues As Long

ColumnToPlaceValues = Worksheets("Emails").Range("A:A").Column


For Each rcell In Worksheets("Report").Range("C2:L1000").Cells
  
    Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnToPlaceValues).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rcell.Value

Next rcell

Columns(ColumnToPlaceValues).RemoveDuplicates

Worksheets("Emails").Range("$A$2:$A$10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
        xlYes


End Sub"